# Extract icons from exe in Rust?

Tags: windows, winapi, rust, simd, bevy

I have the path to an exe.

How do I get a `Vec<RgbaImage<u8>>` of the images contained within?

I'm fine using Windows-specific APIs.

I'm also using Bevy, so math structs from that is preferred.

Answer (score 3):

We can extract the [icon handles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-icons) from the exe, then convert the icon handles to `image` crate images.

The error handling is probably wonky, but this should be enough to get started.

https://github.com/TeamDman/Cursor-Hero/blob/51611380997d74f74f76fa776be4892a9906c005/crates/winutils/src/win_icons.rs

https://github.com/TeamDman/Cursor-Hero/blob/51611380997d74f74f76fa776be4892a9906c005/crates/math/src/shuffle.rs

```rust
use crate::win_errors::*;
use cursor_hero_math::prelude::bgra_to_rgba;
use image::ImageBuffer;
use image::RgbaImage;
use itertools::Itertools;
use widestring::U16CString;
use windows::core::PCWSTR;
use windows::Win32::Graphics::Gdi::CreateCompatibleDC;
use windows::Win32::Graphics::Gdi::DeleteDC;
use windows::Win32::Graphics::Gdi::DeleteObject;
use windows::Win32::Graphics::Gdi::GetDIBits;
use windows::Win32::Graphics::Gdi::SelectObject;
use windows::Win32::Graphics::Gdi::BITMAPINFO;
use windows::Win32::Graphics::Gdi::BITMAPINFOHEADER;
use windows::Win32::Graphics::Gdi::DIB_RGB_COLORS;
use windows::Win32::UI::Shell::ExtractIconExW;
use windows::Win32::UI::WindowsAndMessaging::DestroyIcon;
use windows::Win32::UI::WindowsAndMessaging::GetIconInfoExW;
use windows::Win32::UI::WindowsAndMessaging::HICON;
use windows::Win32::UI::WindowsAndMessaging::ICONINFOEXW;

pub fn get_images_from_exe(executable_path: &str) -> Result<Vec<RgbaImage>> {
    unsafe {
        let path_cstr = U16CString::from_str(executable_path)?;
        let path_pcwstr = PCWSTR(path_cstr.as_ptr());
        let num_icons_total = ExtractIconExW(path_pcwstr, -1, None, None, 0);
        if num_icons_total == 0 {
            return Ok(Vec::new()); // No icons extracted
        }

        let mut large_icons = vec![HICON::default(); num_icons_total as usize];
        let mut small_icons = vec![HICON::default(); num_icons_total as usize];
        let num_icons_fetched = ExtractIconExW(
            path_pcwstr,
            0,
            Some(large_icons.as_mut_ptr()),
            Some(small_icons.as_mut_ptr()),
            num_icons_total,
        );

        if num_icons_fetched == 0 {
            return Ok(Vec::new()); // No icons extracted
        }

        let images = large_icons
            .iter()
            .chain(small_icons.iter())
            .map(|icon| convert_hicon_to_rgba_image(icon))
            .filter_map(|r| match r {
                Ok(img) => Some(img),
                Err(e) => {
                    eprintln!("Failed to convert HICON to RgbaImage: {:?}", e);
                    None
                }
            })
            .collect_vec();

        large_icons
            .iter()
            .chain(small_icons.iter())
            .filter(|icon| !icon.is_invalid())
            .map(|icon| DestroyIcon(*icon))
            .filter_map(|r| r.err())
            .for_each(|e| eprintln!("Failed to destroy icon: {:?}", e));

        Ok(images)
    }
}

pub fn convert_hicon_to_rgba_image(hicon: &HICON) -> Result<RgbaImage> {
    unsafe {
        let mut icon_info = ICONINFOEXW::default();
        icon_info.cbSize = std::mem::size_of::<ICONINFOEXW>() as u32;

        if !GetIconInfoExW(*hicon, &mut icon_info).as_bool() {
            return Err(Error::from_win32().with_description(format!(
                "icon • GetIconInfoExW: {} {}:{}",
                file!(),
                line!(),
                column!()
            )));
        }
        let hdc_screen = CreateCompatibleDC(None);
        let hdc_mem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc_screen);
        let hbm_old = SelectObject(hdc_mem, icon_info.hbmColor);

        let mut bmp_info = BITMAPINFO {
            bmiHeader: BITMAPINFOHEADER {
                biSize: std::mem::size_of::<BITMAPINFOHEADER>() as u32,
                biWidth: icon_info.xHotspot as i32 * 2,
                biHeight: -(icon_info.yHotspot as i32 * 2),
                biPlanes: 1,
                biBitCount: 32,
                biCompression: DIB_RGB_COLORS.0,
                ..Default::default()
            },
            ..Default::default()
        };

        let mut buffer: Vec<u8> =
            vec![0; (icon_info.xHotspot * 2 * icon_info.yHotspot * 2 * 4) as usize];

        if GetDIBits(
            hdc_mem,
            icon_info.hbmColor,
            0,
            icon_info.yHotspot * 2,
            Some(buffer.as_mut_ptr() as *mut _),
            &mut bmp_info,
            DIB_RGB_COLORS,
        ) == 0
        {
            return Err(Error::from_win32().with_description(format!(
                "GetDIBits: {} {}:{}",
                file!(),
                line!(),
                column!()
            )));
        }
        // Clean up
        SelectObject(hdc_mem, hbm_old);
        DeleteDC(hdc_mem);
        DeleteDC(hdc_screen);
        DeleteObject(icon_info.hbmColor);
        DeleteObject(icon_info.hbmMask);

        bgra_to_rgba(buffer.as_mut_slice());

        let image = ImageBuffer::from_raw(icon_info.xHotspot * 2, icon_info.yHotspot * 2, buffer)
            .ok_or_else(|| Error::ImageContainerNotBigEnough)?;
        return Ok(image);
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use bevy::math::IVec4;
    use std::path::PathBuf;

    #[test]
    fn test_convert_hicon_to_rgba_image() {
        let exe_path = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe";
        let icons = super::get_images_from_exe(exe_path).unwrap();

        // Ensure the expected amount is present
        assert_eq!(icons.len(), 30);

        // Save icons
        let mut path = PathBuf::from("target/app_icons");
        path.push("msedge.exe");
        std::fs::create_dir_all(&path).unwrap();
        for (i, icon) in icons.iter().enumerate() {
            let mut icon_path = path.clone();
            icon_path.push(format!("{}.png", i));
            icon.save(icon_path).unwrap();
        }

        // Assert all icons are more than just transparent images
        // Also count rgb totals
        let mut passed = vec![false; icons.len()];
        for (i, icon) in icons.iter().enumerate() {
            let mut rgb_count = IVec4::ZERO;
            for pixel in icon.pixels() {
                let pixel = IVec4::new(
                    pixel[0] as i32,
                    pixel[1] as i32,
                    pixel[2] as i32,
                    pixel[3] as i32,
                );
                rgb_count += pixel;
            }
            if rgb_count != IVec4::ZERO {
                passed[i] = true;
            }
        }
        println!("{:?}", passed);
        assert!(passed.iter().all(|&x| x));
    }
}
```

This uses the `bgra_to_rgba` fn, which is accelerated using [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_instruction,_multiple_data)

```rust
#[cfg(target_arch = "x86")]
use std::arch::x86::_mm_shuffle_epi8;
use std::arch::x86_64::__m128i;
use std::arch::x86_64::_mm_loadu_si128;
use std::arch::x86_64::_mm_setr_epi8;
#[cfg(target_arch = "x86_64")]
use std::arch::x86_64::_mm_shuffle_epi8;
use std::arch::x86_64::_mm_storeu_si128;

/// Convert BGRA to RGBA
/// 
/// Uses SIMD to go fast
pub fn bgra_to_rgba(data: &mut [u8]) {
    // The shuffle mask for converting BGRA -> RGBA
    let mask: __m128i = unsafe {
        _mm_setr_epi8(
            2, 1, 0, 3, // First pixel
            6, 5, 4, 7, // Second pixel
            10, 9, 8, 11, // Third pixel
            14, 13, 12, 15, // Fourth pixel
        )
    };
    // For each 16-byte chunk in your data
    for chunk in data.chunks_exact_mut(16) {
        let mut vector = unsafe { _mm_loadu_si128(chunk.as_ptr() as *const __m128i) };
        vector = unsafe { _mm_shuffle_epi8(vector, mask) };
        unsafe { _mm_storeu_si128(chunk.as_mut_ptr() as *mut __m128i, vector) };
    }
}
```

[image: Windows explorer showing pngs of Microsoft Edge icons]